# Animation with hand on button

Tags: flutter

I am creating an MCQ type app where user selects one option out of 4. I have created a logic for the MCQ screen.

```
bool isSelectedUser = person.uid == toUserRef.uid;
String name = '${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}';
return SizedBox(
      width: 170,
      height: 70,
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        style: ButtonStyle(
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
          ),
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(isSelectedUser
              ? Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8)
              : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3)),
        ),
        child: Text(
          name,
          maxLines: 2,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
        ),
      ));
```

which looks like this

[image]

Now I want to show the exact button selected by the user with a hand pointing towards the option.
Something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rive has a plugin for flutter where you would probably create the whole button with click animation in the editor, and then import to your flutter app.

https://rive.app/editor